# How to query: aggregate.$match -> $lookup -> where x=11

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two mongo collections which are in a relation:

**contacts_collecion**:

```
{ "contact_id" : "1", "e" : "a1@a.aaa" }
{ "contact_id" : "2", "e" : "a2@a.aaa" }
{ "contact_id" : "3", "e" : "a3@a.aaa" }
...
...
```

**contacts_groups_collection**:

```
{ "contact_id" : "2", "group_id" : "1"  }
{ "contact_id" : "3", "group_id" : "1"  }
{ "contact_id" : "3", "group_id" : "2"  }
...
...
```

So typical many-to-many relation - I have also a groups_collection. Every contact can be in multi groups.

When I query:
`db.contacts.aggregate([{ "$match" : { "a" : false, "e" : /ab/ } }, { "$lookup" : { "from" : "contacts_groups", "localField" : "contact_id", "foreignField" : "contact_id", "as" : "details" } }])`

I get:

```
1) { "contact_id" : "1", "e" : "abcd@gmail.com", "details" : [{ "contact_id" : "1", "group_id" : "1" }, { "contact_id" : "1", "group_id" : "2" }] }
2) { "contact_id" : "2", "e" : "abcdef@gmail.com", "details" : [{ "contact_id" : "2", "group_id" : "2" }, { "contact_id" : "2", "group_id" : "3" }] }
3) { "contact_id" : "3", "e" : "abcdefgh@gmail.com", "details" : [] }
```

**But I would like get only the second row (2), so only those where "group_id" : "3".
How can I do this? 

Is the way I do this 'join and where' most effective?**

Comment: `{ "$match" : { "details.group_id" :"3"} }` after `lookup` ? You can't `where` while `join`.

Comment: @SagarReddy Thanks for reply! so it should look like:
`db.contacts.aggregate([{ "$match" : { "a" : false, "e" : /lysa/ } }, { "$lookup" : { "from" : "contacts_groups", "localField" : "contact_id", "foreignField" : "contact_id", "as" : "details" } }, { "$match" : { "details.group_id" : "3" } }])`

<br>What about performance? Is this combination of $lookup and two $match effective? Is this proper way of doing such filtration? 
<br>I will also add a sorting and skip/limt to this pipeline at the end.

Comment: In general it's specific to your use case and ideally you should limit the no of documents ( which will use the index that you've)  going into lookup stage. You may want to look into possibility of doing lookup other way around if that helps. Try various  indexes and analyse the query. Here more about optimization https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/

Comment: @SagarReddy thanks for the link. I am asking about performance because we will have large collections. The contacts collection about 5 million documents, but contacts_groups collection about 200 million documents.
The query I asked you is for a some kind of browser of contacts in groups. It will behave like `SELECT contacts.*
FROM  dbo.contacts INNER JOIN dbo.contacts_groups ON dbo.contacts.cid = dbo.contacts_groups.cid
WHERE dbo.contacts.email LIKE '%a%' AND dbo.contacts_groups.gid = '1'
ORDER BY dbo.contacts.email`. I will have a C# GUI for it with pagination and sorting by columns.

Comment: @SagarReddy feel free to add your first hint as "answer". I will make it as "accepted".

Comment: **The performance case is opened and if anyone has some clues I will really appreciate it.**